# Javascript Function to Obscure Email Using Asterisks?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a password reset page where a user types in their username. I'd like to let them know what email it was sent to (sometimes we forget what email we used), without revealing too much information.

So rather than showing: `joe_awesome@example.com` I'd like to do the following: `jo*********@example.com` in javascript.

How would I do this efficiently? Basically I'd only like to show the first two letters and the domain only.

P.S. I'm new to javascript. Thanks!

Comment: Don't do it in javascript, inspect element will ruin you security. Do it serverside.

Comment: Thanks toby! Actually I'm using Parse's Cloud Code so it should be pretty safe up there (server side). I rather return a "sanitized" string to my client than one that isn't.

Comment: So your JavaScript is running server side on a node server or something like it ? And what's with all the down votes ?

Comment: I believe so. And I'm not sure why people are voting it down, it's a totally valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your email is well formatted and the name has at least 3 characters the solution bellow should work.

```
var email = "joe_awesome@example.com";
function formatEmail(emilString){
    var splitEmail = emilString.split("@")
    var domain = splitEmail[1];
    var name = splitEmail[0];
    return  name.substring(0,3).concat("*********@").concat(domain)
}
console.log(formatEmail(email));
```

In case you want the strings to have the same lengths although i don't recommend it.

```
function formatEmailSameLength(emilString){
    var splitEmail = emilString.split("@")
    var domain = splitEmail[1];
    var name = splitEmail[0];
    return  name.substring(0,3).concat(Array(name.length-3).join("*")).concat("@").concat(domain)
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see. so the first one obscures the actual length. Cool thanks!

Comment: @KingPolygon no problem, just make sure the mail is valid, and the username has at least the characters, if not it will throw and Exception.

Answer (score -1):

Just a different answer

```
const maskEmail = (mail) => {
    let mailUsername = mail.split("@")[0];
    mailUsername = mailUsername[0] + mailUsername.substring(1).replace(/./gi, '*')
    let mailDomain = mail.split("@")[1].split(".")[0].replace(/./gi, '*');
    let mailTld = mail.split("@")[1].split(".")[1].replace(/./gi, '*')

    return `${mailUsername}@${mailDomain}.${mailTld}`
}
```

Comment: This leaks the length of the domain and the name, so I wouldn't recommend it (depending on your privacy requirements).